# Uses of javascript, not just for aesthetics but uses on the server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, backbone.js

I have read this [article (Uses of Javascript)](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/javascript-uses/), while it is right I know there are other uses of javascript, modern javascript nowadays. I haven't read about node.js and how this one works but I have heard that this one makes js do server-side stuffs?

The question is, what are other uses of javascript, can this replace php and ruby? I know this might not be a good idea for enterprise applications but will work well with medium-size applications, am I right?

What are the other uses of javascript other than the one given in the article?

Comment: JavaScript can do anything, just like any other programming language. The eco-system is extremely large by default, though, every browser understands it and a lot of frameworks use it, e.g. as embedded scripting language in a GUI application, server-specific services using nodejs, and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript can very well be used server side. If you're on an IIS server, you can for example use [**JScript**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/72bd815a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [**nodejs**](http://blog.modulus.io/absolute-beginners-guide-to-nodejs), [**v8cgi**](https://code.google.com/p/teajs/) (currently known as TeaJS), or a combination of these. On *nix servers nodejs is a popular framework. Nodejs can even be used to program your own webserver (e.g. using the [**expressjs**](http://expressjs.com/) framework).

Dive in the given links and see what's possible.

Comment: I think that you need to create webserver in order to use NodeJS. And expressjs is just a wrapper around what NodeJS provide.

Comment: NodeJS HTTP module is the web server, indeed. NodeJS can do any kind of server work though, it is not restricted to just HTTP.

Comment: @jcubic: there's a myriad of possibilities: you can use your regular web server to connect to a local nodejs server on a local port, program a full fledged web server using nodejs, create your own modules etc. The point is: server side javascript can be used to create full fledged web application without the use of other programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

There is [TESSEL](http://technical.io/) and [Espruino](http://www.espruino.com/) javascript inside microcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

I use Node.js for web application for few years, few projects and really happy so far.

The Express.js + MongoDB makes a perfect match (exactly as PHP + MySQL, 5 years ago). You can find reference on [MEAN](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/49262866911/the-mean-stack-mongodb-expressjs-angularjs-and) stack.

It works good no only for small applications. We have medium-size app that could be easily scaled up.

Node.js is not to about substitute PHP or Ruby, but what's happening now is indeed, it's more and more used for web applications nowaday. The reason is simple, Node.js has "web-oriented" core, meaning it's originally created to aim highly productive tcp/http applications. With some progress beautiful web development frameworks appeared on top of Node.js that makes web application development even more easy and fun.

For me, programming Node.js on server makes a lot of sense, since JavaScript is main client-side language (almost without alternatives), so *context-switching* between client/server programming is less. With practice you get use to some initial JavaScript *weirdness* and things goes smooth and nice.